# open liberty won't start app after initial startup

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty, liberty-maven-plugin

I'm using the liberty-maven-plugin v3.7.1 to start an app in liberty (mvn liberty:dev).  My pom setting is listed below.  When I run this the first time, with no server in the liberty wlp directory, it works. When I stop the server & run a second time, it fails with the messages below, which do not indicate what the issue is.

If I go to C:\dev\wlp\usr\servers & delete the localServer directory that was created initially then I can start the app with liberty-maven-plugin ( mvn liberty:dev). But it will once again fail to start a second time.

Any ideas what the issue is?

**exceptions**

```
[DEBUG] (org.codehaus.mojo.pluginsupport.ant.AntHelper) CWWKM2014I: Now looking for CWWKZ0001I.*app in messages.log.
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: CWWKM2187E: Failed to deploy the app application. The application start message was not found in the log file.
        at io.openliberty.tools.maven.applications.DeployMojoSupport.verifyAppStarted(DeployMojoSupport.java:221)
        at io.openliberty.tools.maven.applications.DeployMojo.installAndVerifyApp(DeployMojo.java:220)
        at io.openliberty.tools.maven.applications.DeployMojo.installLooseApplication(DeployMojo.java:189)
        at io.openliberty.tools.maven.applications.DeployMojo.installProject(DeployMojo.java:167)
        at io.openliberty.tools.maven.applications.DeployMojo.doExecute(DeployMojo.java:81)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.pluginsupport.MojoSupport.execute(MojoSupport.java:122)
        
        
        
        
        [DEBUG] action.exception.stacktrace: com.ibm.ws.install.InstallException: CWWKF1250I: The following assets already exist: [javaee-8.0, localConnector-1.0, monitor-1.0, restConnector-2.0]. They will not be reinstalled. To modify an existing feature, you must manually uninstall it first.
        at com.ibm.ws.install.internal.ExceptionUtils.create(ExceptionUtils.java:127)
        at com.ibm.ws.install.internal.ExceptionUtils.createByKey(ExceptionUtils.java:116)
        at com.ibm.ws.install.internal.InstallKernelMap.singleFileResolve(InstallKernelMap.java:935)
        at com.ibm.ws.install.internal.InstallKernelMap.get(InstallKernelMap.java:299)
        at com.ibm.ws.install.map.InstallMap.get(InstallMap.java:273)
        at io.openliberty.tools.common.plugins.util.InstallFeatureUtil.installFeatures(InstallFeatureUtil.java:451)
        at io.openliberty.tools.maven.server.InstallFeatureMojo.installFeatures(InstallFeatureMojo.java:62)
```

pom.xml config

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>io.openliberty.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <installDirectory>C:\dev\wlp</installDirectory>
            </configuration>
        <!-- Specify configuration, executions for liberty-maven-plugin -->
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Make sure you dont have any open files/directories in `C:\dev\wlp` tree, also make sure that you are actually stopping the running server before starting it again (no java processes). I used `liberty:dev` task and only noticed strange behavior when some files where locked.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest opening an issue at https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.maven/issues. If you can provide a sample project to recreate, that would be ideal. The second invocation of 'mvn liberty:dev' should be able to start the application. This sounds like a bug.